# expose application to IP range or validate a login requet against an IP range

Tags: wakanda

Is there a Wakanda way to:

1. expose a Wakanda application only to a specific IP address or IP range
2. validate a login request (custom login) against an IP address or IP range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer the questions one by one :

1-

This should be done using your OS' firewall (using iptables for instance if you are on Linux)

2-

If you restrict access to the app using the firewall, you might not need to do this. But if you really need to :

Today there is no good way to do this, because you can't disable the [authentication REST API](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Wakanda%20Studio/0.Beta/Authenticating-Users.201-814507.en.html). The workaround I propose is as follows (but I don't think it will work if you are using active directory ):

- Add a custom request handler for authentication `/login` where you do something like :

  ```
  function login(request,response){
          var ip = request.remoteAddress;

          if( ! isIPAuthorized(ip)){
                          response.statusCode = 403;
                          return;
          }

          sessionStorage["login-request"] = true;
          /*
           * Your login code here
           * For instance you can use loginByPassword, createUserSession ..
           */
          sessionStorage["login-request"] = false;
  }
  ```
- Inside your `Login Listener` you can check if the login request came from you custom login function or not by checking the `sessionStorage` :

  ```
  if(!sessionStorage["login-request"]){
          return {
                 "error" : 1024,
                  "errorMessage" : "Unautorized Login Attempt"
          }
  }
  ```

This way any login attempt using the default REST authentication API where IPs are not checked will be refused.

Comment: thanks for your response Hamza. is there any way to access the `request` object in the custom login handler (inside the required.js file) of the the solution?

Comment: Today it is not possible. I will discuss this with the team to see if we can have something like `httpServer.getRequest()` to access the request attached to the current thread as an [HttpRequest](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/HTTP-Request-Handlers/HTTPRequest.201-803366.en.html)

Comment: that'd be great and would open lot's of possibilities. thank you

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I tried implementing this and whenever I modify the default guest session by adding the IP address to `currentSession().storage`, Wakanda fails to load the storage object returned by my LoginListener in required.js into the session.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to expose *any* application to a specific range of IP addresses (*while blocking all others*) is with a [firewall](/questions/tagged/firewall); whether it be a software-based firewall (such as [iptables](/questions/tagged/iptables) or [windows-firewall](/questions/tagged/windows-firewall)) or a hardware-based firewall (such as a <kbd>Cisco ASA</kbd>). Using a firewall completely alleviates the need for the second part of your question.

Answer (score -1):

For the first question, enable the [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Architecture-of-Wakanda-Applications/Project/Project-Settings.300-1024018.en.html) in the Project Settings file ( Settings.waSettings ), and you need to define the list of  Domain name or IP address from where external pages are allowed to send data requests to the Wakanda Server via CORS. Multiple domain attributes can be added to create a white list.